# How to read line from console synchronously in ts-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am working on a `node.js` application which shows some menu options on console and asks for input (1-5). Application is in `tyepscript`.

So I can print my menu using `console.log()`.

```
console.log('1: Option#1');
console.log('2: Option#2');
console.log('3: Option#3');
console.log('4: Option#4');

// some way to read input from console
var opt = readFromConsole();  // HOW TO READ?

// perform some action on the basis of those options
someAction();
```

But how to read from console synchronously in `tyepscript`?

I found one `node.js` module [`readline-sync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync). But it seems to work of `node.js` applications. My application is totally `typescript` based. So is there any `typescript` module which I can use to fullfill my purpose? Or, in any way can I use [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) for my purpose?

Any kind of help/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> read from console synchronously

You can make async code -> sync with a careful while loop + setTimeout, but I would advise against that. Instead just use the built in async readline : https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html